# How to compile and run a C# Windows Forms application without visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'd like to run a windows form application, programmed in visual studio, but I need to be able to run this program from a machine they does not have VS installed at all. I'm a computer science student so I've attained a lot of software for free through the university I attend, unfortunately I do not believe I am able to download more than one copy, but I've created a small program that needs to be able to run on a machine without any programming environments installed.
so my questions are:
Is this possible? 
would I need to change settings on the form or on my VS?

if it is completely not possible, I will just need to work around this some other way. Any insight would be great, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com)?

Comment: Just build it in visual studio with release configuration. You don't need vs to run it.

Comment: You need the .Net framework your app is targeting. That mat already be installed, otherwise find the redistributable for it.

Comment: [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/tour/090/formsdesigner.asp) /

Comment: if you deploy the source code, you will need such tools to compile. But build it and deploy the executable/dll and you will be able to run the exe without any additional ide(s) as long as the proper version of .NET Framework is installed

Comment: if you need to compile the source code on another machine, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) would also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

if you install framework 4.0,4.5 etc, you can run it

Comment: And what if the project is set up for .NET 3.5 SP1 ? You're probably right but it's a guess.

Comment: For what is worth, .net framework is compatible with earlier versions.